# Dataframe manipulation with dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, plyr, na, dplyr

Here is a very small portion of my data frame, df :

```
     row.names   AB1         AB4         CB4852      CB4853      CB4854   CB4856         L1
1   1_n         582.000       NA        375.00000   113.00000   160.0000 133.00000        1
2   1_meanTOF   157.433       NA        44.62667    51.23009    42.5875  66.63158         1
3   1_medianTOF 148.000       NA        38.00000    40.00000    31.5000  45.00000         1
4   1_minTOF    20.000        NA        20.00000    20.00000    20.0000  21.00000         1
79  2_n         637.0000    644.0000    460.0000    40.0       487.0000     NA            2
80  2_meanTOF   171.6311    210.4984    176.0478    49.5       189.8439     NA            2
81  2_medianTOF 155.0000    189.0000    81.5000     45.5       116.0000     NA            2
82  2_minTOF    21.0000     20.0000      20.0000    21.0        20.0000     NA            2
```

I have been stumped on this for the past day. Notice the row numbers skip 1-4 … 79-82. Every 78 rows there is a split, the splits correspond to a different set. There are 30 sets of 78 for a grand total of 2340 rows, each set has the same row names except for a change in the set number (e.g #_name). Additionally there are a total of 97 columns, 96 of which have strain names in them and 1 (named L1) has a factor (1-30) that I have been using to try and split the data frame to do work on it (no success yet). Finally, and most importantly, Notice the placement of the NAs, specifically - they are in different columns for each set.

This is what I would like to do with this data.

1) Split df by factor column L1 into 30 individual sets (this can alternatively be done by splitting the data set by each 78 rows). I have been attempting this with both dplyr and plyr with no success.

2) Remove columns that contain NA in ALL rows - this corresponds to a particular strain being lost from the dataset. Some columns have NAs for certain rows - I want to keep these.

I have a function for this step that works, though I am unsure how to integrate it:

```
na.rm.fun <- function(x){
  x[,colSums(is.na(x))<nrow(x)]
  return(x)
}
```

3) Remove Factor column "L1" because once split, I no longer need. This can be done prior to split if not using it to split. This is a straightforward command using:

```
> select(df, -L1)
```

4) Save each individual set as a separate .Rda file. I attempted to create a for loop function to do this step, and I believe it is feasible, though I am at a loss on how to do assignments in a loop

```
save.fun <- function(x){
  for(i in 1:30){
    z <- x[(78*i-77):(78*i),]
    save(z, file = paste("pheno_plate_", i, ".Rda", sep = ""))
  }}
save.fun(df)
```

When run on my initial df this splits it up in 78 row increments and saves the corresponding file, unfortunately I am unsure how to assign z_i through z_i+29 so I can load them up once saved. Additionally, I mad this loop prior to removing columns with all NAs, though I suppose I can do this afterwards by loading the 30 data.frames and running my remove NA function. I am curious how to make this work in dplyr

Last note. If I change the save function script to this :

```
save.fun <- function(x){
  for(i in 1:30){
    z <- x[1:78,]
    save(z, file = paste("pheno_plate_", i, ".Rda", sep = ""))
  }}
```

And run dplyr like so:

```
df %.%
  group_by(L1) %.%
  do(na.rm.fun) %.%
  do(save.fun)
```

I notice two things :
1) All of the saved files correspond to set 30, I assume this is because of the for loop
2) (more importantly) ANY column that is completely NA in ANY set is completely removed from ALL file sets. I thought this was interesting and am wondering how to use dplyr in such a way to avoid this issue.

As always, Any and all help is much appreciated.

Comment: You might try `saveRDS` instead of `save()`, see [here](http://www.fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2012/04/01/saving-and-loading-r-objects/).

Comment: You may have better luck getting help if you post a minimal working example, i.e., the column `L1` sounds very important, so you should include it in your sample data. And your sample should probably have a row or two where everything else in `NA`, since one of the goals to remove those rows. I bet you could create a 6 by 10 (or smaller!) working sample that has most of the characteristics necessary to generalize up.

Comment: @shujaa thanks for the tip, I included the L1 column for this example. I don't want to remove rows with NAs, only columns in each set of 78 where all rows are NA

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to start an answer to address a few problems, rather than continuing to comment. I'm not sure if this will get you the whole way there, but hopefully it's a good start.

You're on the right track in that if you can right functions to do everything to each little piece of your data.frame, `dplyr::do` should make it easy to apply them to the whole thing. This is preferred to using for loops.

### Row names

First, row names/numbers don't work how you think they do. The numbers on the left side are actually stored as row names, which you can see if you run `row.names(df)`. This makes your choice of `"row.names"` for a column name unfortunate, I would change that column name to, say, `"group"`. (The rest of my answer will assume you've made this change.)

Whatever the row names are integer or not, the first row is row if you do `df[1, ]`, and the 78th row is row `df[78, ]`, and if you run `df[78, ]` you'll see that the actual `row.name` *isn't* 78 (since your `row.names` aren't sequential). So let's not rely on that numbering for very much.

### Saving

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to save. I think "each individual set" means the 4-row data.frame with all-NA columns removed. And let's assume that it's being applied to one piece, `x`, of the already-split data frame. All we need to do is save that piece, no for-loop required.

It also looks like you want the name of the file to be `"pheno_plate_i"` where `i` is replaced by the value of `L1`. So let's **not** delete the `L1` column. I haven't tested this, but it should at least get you on the right track.

```
save.fun <- function(x){
    saveRDS(select(x, -L1), file = sprintf("pheno_plate_%s.rds", x[1, "L1"]))
}
```

Including `L1` in the saved object in addition to coding it in the file name seems less error-prone than relying on file name alone.

### Putting it together

Your NA removal looks good, so then just call everything sequentially with `dplyr`, it doesn't look like you have problems with that.

### Response to comments:

#### Loading RDS

Take a look at `?saveRDS`. There's a corresponding load function, `readRDS`. Use that to open them.

#### Splitting

If you use `dplyr`, the `group_by()` call does the splitting. All the other functions will only see the split pieces, so you don't need to try to split them again in the save function.

#### row.names

Re-reading your question and comments, I understand your data structure now. I thought your actual data skipped rows 5-78 like your posted sample, and that was why you were calling attention to the missing rows. Now I see that you just omitted them to make a nice concise example. But use `dplyr` and `L1` for splitting, and don't worry about row numbers.

Comment: before working through your solution let me just say that the row.names column in my data set are the row names. the posted df is the result of me typing View(df) and copy and pasting from the view window. so, there is no column names row.names, that is the data attribute row.names. I will go through your response when i have more time

Comment: also let me be clear on what i want saved. each chunk of 78 rows in the data frame with entire NA columns removed and L1 column removed - saved as separate files in a folder.

Comment: Okay, the what you want saved makes sense. I edited the `save.fun` to eliminate not select `L1`. And glad to hear the row names isn't an issue. However, then I'm pretty confused what you're doing with 77 and 78 in this part of your question: `z <- x[(78*i-77):(78*i),]` since those seem to correspond to actual names rather than the row numbers.

Comment: notice that that is in the save.fun function, for(i in 1:30). This means this goes through the data frame and chunks it by row number like this : 1-78 then 79-156 then 157-234… and so on. This is indicated by what you said in your response, to split up df by rows you need to use df[rows,columns]. Also, I can not open .rds files in R studio… is this the case or am i doing something wrong? The files also don't contain any information in regular R.